# Why can't my nextJS app find my firebase cloud function?

Tags: firebase, next.js, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to trigger my firebase cloud function from an API route in NextJS. Essentially, my API listens for a webhook from an e-signature API.
The function deploys without error and the project deploys to Vercel.

When I sign the test contract (which sends the webhook, triggering the function) I get errors:

```
Error processing webhook: [FirebaseError: not-found] {
  code: 'functions/not-found',
  customData: undefined,
  details: undefined
}
Error triggering Cloud function:  [FirebaseError: not-found] {
  code: 'functions/not-found',
  customData: undefined,
  details: undefined
}
```

Here is my API route code that listens for the webhook (pages/api/esignaturesWebhook.js). (I have removed databaseURL and project name for security)

```
import { db } from "@/firebaseConfig";
import {  updateDoc, doc, setDoc } from "firebase/firestore";
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { getFunctions, httpsCallable } from 'firebase/functions';
import admin from "../../server/firebase-admin";


export default async function handler(req, res) {
  if (req.method === "POST") {
    try {
      const app = initializeApp({
        credential: admin.credential.cert({
            projectId: process.env.PROJECT_ID,
            clientEmail: process.env.CLIENT_EMAIL,
            privateKey: process.env.PRIVATE_KEY
        }),
        databaseURL: '{URL}'
      }, "{projectName}")
      
      const functions = getFunctions(app, "europe-west2");
      // console.log("functions =>", functions)
      // Parse JSON in the request body
      // console.log("RECEIVED WEBHOOK BODY", req.body)
      const webhookData = req.body;
      const companyName = webhookData.data.contract.company_name
      const userId = webhookData.data.contract.metadata
      console.log("WEBHOOK USERID=> ", userId, "WEBHOOK COMPANYNAME =>", companyName)


      // Process the webhook data as needed
      const personRef = doc(db, "Organisations", companyName, "people", userId)
      const pdfUrl = webhookData.data.contract.contract_pdf_url

      // console.log("PDF URL BEING SENT TO CLOUD FUNCTION =>", pdfUrl)

      const dateTimeID = new Date().toString()
      const webhookDocRef = doc(db, "Webhooks", dateTimeID);

      // Set the document with the webhookData
      await setDoc(webhookDocRef, webhookData); 
      if (webhookData.status === "contract-signed") {
        console.log("PASSED THE IF STATEMENT")
        //Get the metadata out of the webhookData which will contain the document ID in the people collection.
        await updateDoc(personRef, {surrenderContractSigned: true})
        //Trigger the cloud function to download the pdf from webhookData.data.contract.contract_pdf_url and upload to storage bucket 
        const processPdf = httpsCallable(functions, "processPdf")
        const functionResponse = await processPdf({pdfUrl, userId, companyName})
        console.log("ProcessPdf instance =>", processPdf)
  
        console.log("Cloud Function Response => :", functionResponse);
      }
      if (webhookData.status === "signer-declined") {
        await updateDoc(personRef, {surrenderContractDeclined: true})
      }
      console.log("Webhook received:", webhookData);

      // Respond with a 200 OK status
      res.status(200).end();
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error processing webhook:", error);
      res.status(500).end("Internal Server Error");
      console.log("Error triggering Cloud function: ", error)
    }
  } else {
    // Respond to non-POST requests with a 405 Method Not Allowed status
    res.status(405).end("Method Not Allowed");
  }
}
```

And here is the firebase cloud function itself (again, removed bucketURL for security):

```
/* eslint-disable */ 
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const {storage} = require("firebase-admin");
const axios = require("axios");
const {getStorage} = require('firebase-admin/storage');

const {credential} = require("firebase-admin");
const admin = require('firebase-admin');



admin.initializeApp({
  credential: credential.applicationDefault(),
})

const bucket = getStorage().bucket("{bucketURL}");

exports.processPdf = functions.region("europe-west2").https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
    try {
      const { pdfUrl, userId, companyName } = data;

      functions.logger.log("LOGGER --------- >PDFURL => ", pdfUrl);

      const pdfBuffer = await downloadPdf(pdfUrl);
      const pdfFileName = `${userId}_surrender_contract_signed.pdf`;

      await uploadPdfToStorage(pdfBuffer, pdfFileName, userId, companyName);
      return {
        result: "PDF processed successfully"
      }
    } catch (error) {
      functions.logger.log("Error processing PDF:", error);
      throw new functions.https.HttpsError("internal", "Internal Server Error");
    }
});

async function downloadPdf(pdfUrl) {

  const response = await axios.get(pdfUrl, { responseType: "arraybuffer" });
  return Buffer.from(response.data, "binary");
}

async function uploadPdfToStorage(pdfBuffer, pdfFileName, userId, companyName) {
  const filePath = `${companyName}/people/${userId}/${pdfFileName}`;
  const file = bucket.file(filePath);
  await file.save(pdfBuffer);
  console.log(`PDF uploaded to storage: ${pdfFileName}`);
}
```

I suspect it might have something to do with how I am calling initializeApp in the API file, but I don't know how else to do it and that's only a guess.

Thanks for your help

I have tried changing where I call the initializeApp and tried examining logs, but I'm only ever getting the FirebaseError: not-found

Comment: I solved this. I just needed to import app from my firebase-config file rather than re-initialize app using the admin sdk